# On Mac, why doesn't alias la 'ls -la' work?

Tags: mac, terminal, alias

When I run `alias la 'ls -la'` I get the error: `ls: alias: no such file or directory`

How do I alias `la` to `ls -la`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mac is probably using bash as shell, so you need to type `alias la='ls -la'` instead of `alias la 'ls -la'`